# select two columns merged in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I actually need to select two columns using one alias in mysql. That is I need to select two columns say email and user_email as one email column. I am not looking for concat. I need to get two fields merged like array merging in php

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly need. Can you show your code?

Comment: Why do you have two fields with similar - if not the same - values? 
If you have something like workplace_email and personal_email, I get that. Can you be more specific please? You do need a union though and Cheruvian is right. Possibly a redesign is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a union.  Though you may want to reconsider your DB design if you are thinking this way.

```
Select email From Table
Union
Select user_email From table
```

Comment: i have almost 1 million records and union showing lost mysql connection error

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use a union.

```
select email
from mytable
union
select user_email
from mytable
```

This way both columns will have the same alias, email, and they will be in one column.